# Is it possible to combine postggres’ ts_headline, ts_rank_cd, and pg_tgrm (fuzzy search)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I am currently trying to implement a full text search query that displays results with a headline and in ranked order but also permits fuzzy searching. Apologies for the query term 'torture', I am building a human rights text search engine.

I have achieved the first two objectives but I am unsure how to amend my query to implement pg_tgrm's method of fuzzy search. I'm also unsure if this functionality is compatible.

The following query achieves the first two objectives:

```
SELECT item_id, 
       requests_url, 
       ts_headline('english', entire_text, query, 'StartSel = , StopSel = , ShortWord = 1') 
       as entire_text_highlights 
FROM (SELECT item_id, requests_url, entire_text, ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, query) 
AS rank,query 
FROM processed_judgment_html, websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'torture') AS query 
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ query ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10) AS query_results;
```

The following code was a go at trying to implement pg_trgm, however, it took two minutes to return a limit of 1 result and did not find a relevant result, when I intentionally misspelt torture to 'tarture' the first result did not contain the word torture.

```
SELECT item_id, 
       requests_url, 
       ts_headline('english', entire_text, query, 'StartSel = '', StopSel = '', ShortWord = 1') as         
       entire_text_highlights 
FROM processed_judgment_html, websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'torture') query, NULLIF(ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, query), 0) rank, 
SIMILARITY('tarture', entire_text) similarity 
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ query or similarity > 0 ORDER BY rank DESC, similarity DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1
```

To note, I have created a GIN index for each pg_tgrm and for ts_vector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

For anyone that needs a solution to the above, I avoided the issue and implemented a Python spell check library on the user query before passing it into Postgres

Comment: A pg_trgm index will only work with operators, like `%`. not with functions, like SIMILARITY.  Also, the headline function won't work on something that is not a FTS `@@` match, but only a trigram `%` match.  I would probably run two different queries and combine the results on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm pretty sure it works as the official documentation includes supporting the 'similarity' function along side others - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html